# PDF of $V = \frac{Z_1}{\sqrt{(Z_1^2 + Z_2^2)/2}}$, $Z_i$ are standard normal

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I'm stuck on part B of this textbook problem:

[image: title]

Part A is trivial; recognize the bottom as $\sqrt{U/r}$ where $U$ is $\chi^2(2)$ and $r=2$, and we have a $t$ distribution with 2 degrees of freedom. In part B, the numerator and denominator are dependent, so this trick won't work.

Here's what I've tried:

1. **CDF technique:** Someone in chat suggested simplifying with $Z_1 = \pm\sqrt{Z_1^2}$. Then algebra reveals
   $$P\left( \frac{Z_1}{\sqrt{(Z_1^2 + Z_2^2)/2}} \leq v\right) = P\left((v^2 -2)Z_1^2 + (v^2) Z_2^2\leq 0\right)$$
   but I know nothing about the distribution of the function on the right, other than that it is a linear combination of normal distributions.
2. **MGF technique:** To do this we would need to state $V$ as a linear combination of a function of $Z_1$ and another function of $Z_2$, which I haven't succeeded at.
3. Treat $V$ as a **transformation** of $Z_1$ and $Z_2$, but then there is no inverse.
4. Someone else suggested substituting into **polar coordinates**, but this requires the use of the Rayleigh distribution, which hasn't been taught yet.

I would appreciate a hint on how to solve this using minimal knowledge about the distributions in question.

Comment: Also see https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/377337/119261.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

This is $$ \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{1+(Z_2/Z_1)^2}}$$ so compute the distribution of the ratio of two independent normals (which winds up being Cauchy) and then do a transformation.

**EDIT**
As Michael Hardy points out, actually this is the absolute value of the desired random variable. However, the distribution is symmetric, so you can still do the problem by computing this.

Comment: What you have here is the absolute value of the random variable in the question. But the random variable in the question can be negative.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yep

Comment: Thank you. I *think* I've made this work. As a note to searchers who might have been sent here by the same textbook, this transformation is easiest using the CDF technique; you have to double your probability expression twice (once to undo the absolute value, and again when taking square roots over the inequality).